# How to translate data to ts using ngx translate to angular

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

**component.ts**

I have this code in app.component.ts and it needs to be translated to select option

```
label = ['', 'label1', 'label2']
```

**component.html**

html uses ng For

```
<select>
   <option *ngFor="let value of label">{{value}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [pipe](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core#5-use-the-service-the-pipe-or-the-directive) to translate it in the template.

```
<select>
   <option *ngFor="let value of label">{{value | translate}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: can you describe in more detail how to use pipe

Comment: It's literally in the code. `| translate` after your variable containing the string to be translated. If you're asking how to set up `ngx-translate` then just read the step by step documentation. It's super easy!